# не могу вывести массив

Tags: php

Хочу вывести несколько элементов массива в строку через запятую, но выводится последний так как цикл forech так все обрабатывает помогите пожалуйста все вывести по очереди

```html
if(isset($_FILES))
{

//пролистываем весь массив изображений по одному $_FILES['file']['name'] as $k=>$v
            $error = array();

    foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $k=>$v){

        $uploaddir = 'images/';
        
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir.basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$k]);
        $comma_separated = implode(",", $uploadfilee);



// Копируем файл из каталога для временного хранения файлов:
            if (!copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$k], $uploadfile))
            {

                $error[] = "<div class='dannye'><h3>Ошибка! Не удалось загрузить файл на сервер!</div></h3>";
            }

    }
    print_r($comma_separated);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+ У вас опечатка в строке

```bash
$comma_separated = implode(",", $uploadfilee);
```

переменная `$uploadfilee` не определена да и `$uploadfile` массивом не является.

- для *перемещения* загруженных файлов используют [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)
- для проверки на ошибки в массиве `$_FILES` есть ключ `error`. При удачной загрузке он равен `UPLOAD_ERR_OK`

Конечный код будет выглядеть примерно так

```bash
$success_list = [];
$error_list   = [];
$uploads_dir  = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'images' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

foreach ($_FILES['pictures']['error'] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name     = basename($_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key]);
        $success  = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
        if ($success) {
            $success_list[] = $name;
        }
        else {
            $error_list[] = $name;
        }
    }
    else {
        $error_list[] = $_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
    }
}

$error_list = implode(',', $error_list);
$success_list = implode(',', $success_list);
```

Comment: Спасибо всё работает, только можете пожалуйста объяснить пару строк  $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key]; и эту $error_list[] = $_FILES['file']['name'][$key]; спасибо

Comment: @Koly первая - получение имени временного файла, а вторая - добавление элементов в массив(список с ошибками)

Answer (score 0):

У вас ключ стоит не в том месте и неправильная переменная в цикле, и ключ тоже в цикле не нужен в данном случае:

```
foreach($_FILES as $file)
$file['file']['name']
$file['file']['tmp_name']
```

И смотрите что у вас в массиве `print_r($_FILES)`